# Find a character within a value

Tags: excel, vba

Okay I saw a few similar questions but none that quite addressed my issue.

What I want to do is go through column A and for each cl that contains an `*` (asterisk) I want to change the value to `0`.

If I'm not mistaken an asterisk would have to be treated differently than normal text since it is used in excel coding. If I'm mistaken but you know of another character or word that would have to be treated differently please enlighten us for both the readers and my own knowledge.

Below is what my code should look like and thank you very much for your help

```
For each cl.value in range("A2:A300").
    If cl.value contains "*" then. Cl.value = 0.
End if.
Next cl.
```

Comment: `Instr()` function is your friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few possible ways to write proper `if statement` in VBA in your situation. One could be as follows:

```
For Each cl In Range("A2:A300")
    If InStr(1, cl.Value, "*") > 0 Then
        cl.Value = 0
    End If
Next cl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of Find/Replace and filter for that.

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, Select column A, in the find, put `~*`, and leave the replace empty (the tilde `~` is used to escape special characters).
2. Click "More Options", and click the "Format" button to the right of the replace box.
3. Pick the tab "Fill" and pick a colour, say yellow, then "OK".
4. Make sure that "Match entire cell contents" is unchecked.
5. Replace all in Sheet (this should fill all the cells containing with yellow).
6. Select column A, apply a filter by yellow, select the values and delete (or put 0 in them by typing `0` and dragging down).

You can then remove the fill.

Comment: i´m a complete noob with excel, but still the yellow fill step feels a little bit unnecessary, so i was wondering, isn't it possible to search/replace the value without that extra step ?

Comment: @jambriz This Find/Replace doesn't actually replace anything. It simply adds formatting to the matching cells. You cannot simply Find the character `*` and replace it by nothing, since it would then only remove the `*` and leave all the other contents of the cell intact, which is not the aim of the OP. We need to replace all the cells containing `*` by `0`. The formatting allows you to identify those cells and deal with them all at the same time.

Comment: oh, i had misread the question the first time, i thought it was "replace cells containing exactly `*` with `0`", but instead it is "replace all cells containing a `*` with `0`", so you're right